# How to consume a webApi from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to do project which call api's from database

and make another project and call the old one which contain api's only in its controller

I face those problems
1- I want to return an object from api which takes object and return object
as

this is my api which locate in "testController"

```
  [HttpPost]
            [ActionName("fetch_information")]
            public login_info fetch_information(login_info_request request)
```

and I want to call this api from another project
as

```
      public login_info fetch_information(login_info_request request)
            {

                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58295/fetch_information");


                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/"+request+"").Result;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {              
                    return null;
  here I want to return an object of "login_info " 
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

my question is 
where can I give it request object data "login_info_request "?
and where can I recieve object from api "login_info"?

thanks in advance

Comment: Would making a class library containing your "login_info" and have both projects reference it (so they both use the same) be an option?

Comment: @MarvinSmit Sorry can't understand , but may you tell me where is the error in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you made a GET request whereas the Web API method you have shown expects POST.

So:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:58295/fetch_information");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

login_info_request req = ... 
string postBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/" + request, content).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Read the response body as string
    string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    // deserialize the JSON response returned from the Web API back to a login_info object
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<login_info>(json);
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

And if you use the [`Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries NuGet`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) there is an [`extension method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944541(v=vs.118).aspx) which will allow you to shorten the code:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<login_info>().Result;
}
else
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: api takes object from "login_info_request" and return object from "login_info" where can I give it "login_info_request"

Comment: I see. You made a GET request in your code whereas you should have made a POST request. Let me update my answer to illustrate that.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Forgot to add `.Result` at the end. Answer updated.

Comment: Look at the error response on the client: `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`. You should learn to debug your code.

Comment: Sorry , another question what is the diffrence between req and request in your answer?

Comment: `req` is an instance of `login_info_request` that you should populate and which will be sent to the server as JSON. `request` is something that you had in your initial question and which is unclear where is it coming from. Normally that should be the route to your Web API method, something like `'api/test/fetch_information'`.